# Filling in an 8x8 minesweeper grid with mines (Day 11: Christmas tree edition)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, seasonal, nonogram, minesweeper

<sub>[<kbd>Previous puzzles</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a86115%20is%3aq%20%22filling%20in%20an%208x8%20minesweeper%20grid%20with%20mines%22&searchOn=3)</sub>

<sub>Contains: Single mines (1 mine), Double mines (2 mines), Triple mines (3 mines)</sub>

---

To get the $\color{green}✓$:

> 1. Solve the Nonogram
> 2. Solve the Minesweeper puzzle
>
> Note: partial answers are perfectly okay.

Today's Minesweeper puzzle is a bit weird. Here's why:

> 1. There's a Nonogram. Why, you might ask? That's because since today's puzzle is in the shape of a Christmas tree, that means that there is going to be a Nonogram  to determine the shape of the tree (however I am sorry about it being asymmetrical)
> 2. There are two different "realms" in the puzzle:
>
> - The "Normal" realm. This is literally just the part of the puzzle that's not shaded due to Nonogram rules.
> - The "Starry" realm. Now, this is a bit more complex. For starters, obviously this is the part of the puzzle that is shaded due to Nonogram rules. Secondly, the numbered cells are affected by mines in the Starry realm and mines in the Normal realm. However, numbered cells in the Normal realm do not have their total affected by mines in the Starry realm.
>
> 3. The yellow, red, green, and blue is only for decoration and does not affect the puzzle in any way.

Note that for the Nonogram, you can disregard the outside borders entirely as that is not for the puzzle.

The puzzle:

[image]

Transcribed in text:

Minesweeper grid (accounting for outside borders, includes amount of mines in each realm):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 8 |   |   |y 2|   | 9 |12 |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |14 |   | 9 |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |10 | r | 8 |   |13 |   |10 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 4 | 5 | 6 | 9 | g |r 3|   | 8 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 6 | g |   | 4 | 8 |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 4 |r 8|   |10 |   | 5 |   | 9 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |b 2|   |   |   | g |   | 6 | r |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 6 | 5 | 4 | 8 |   |12 |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

+---------------------------+------------+------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|Normal Realm|Starry Realm|
+---------------------------+------------+------------+
|# of single mines (1 mine) |      5     |      0     |
+---------------------------+------------+------------+
|# of double mines (2 mines)|      6     |      10    |
+---------------------------+------------+------------+
|# of triple mines (3 mines)|      3     |      11    |
+---------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Nonogram (accounting for outside borders)

Rows

```
10
4,5
4,5
3,4
2,3
3,4
2,3
1,1
4,5
10
```

Columns

```
10
7,2
4,1,2
3,2
1,1
3,2
4,1,2
7,2
7,2
10
```

Comment: okay I just realized that I forgot to put the goal for this puzzle in let me edit in quick

Comment: Just a quick correction: the starry realm should have 9 double mines and 10 triple mines, not 10 and 11 respectively as given in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

The solving paths for both the nonogram and the minesweeper are very straightforward, but I can provide intermediate steps if required.

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned the requirement for intermediate steps but yeah if you would be able to please show those

Comment: @CrSb0001 In principle there is no need to mention this, however here the intermediate steps were that straightforward that I didn't think it was necessary to go into them.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense

Comment: Yea, given all the 10s at the border and only two numbers on the rows each, it's clear the shaded cells are simply from the ends. Then for the minesweeper, can start from the 12s and 2s and 6s.